# Swig with CMake not able to find header includes

Tags: c++, c, cmake, swig

I am trying to run swig using CMake and I am getting

```
java.i:9: Error: Unable to find 'api.h'
java.i:10:Error: Unable to find 'TestStruct.h'
```

I have tried setting `USE_LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `SWIG_USE_LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, without any luck. I am probably failing to understand something that is going on. My understanding was that I am linking to the `api` target so those include directories should be visible.

Note: That it works if I copy those headers into the build directory where swig is getting called.

**Any information will be helpful. Thanks.**

**java.i**

```
 %module example
 %include "std_string.i"
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 #include "api.h"
 extern TestStruct TestFunc();
 %}

 %include "api.h"
 %include "TestStruct.h"
 extern TestStruct TestFunc();
```

**CMakeLists.txt for the swig target**

```
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)

set_property(SOURCE java.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(javaExample
  TYPE SHARED
    LANGUAGE java
    SOURCES java.i)

target_include_directories(javaExample PRIVATE ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(javaExample PRIVATE api)
```

**CMakeLists.txt for the api target**

```
add_library( api SHARED 
    inc/api.h
    src/api.cpp
)

target_include_directories( api
  PUBLIC
    inc
)

target_link_libraries( api
  PUBLIC
    FooTypes
  PRIVATE
    FooBar
)

add_subdirectory(src/FooBar)
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. I was unfortunately using cmake 3.10 instead of latest (The default apt repo for cmake is old?). Upgraded to 3.17 and there was no issue.

All that is required is:

`set_property(TARGET javaExample PROPERTY SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TRUE)`

Comment: Yep, this `SWIG_` property was added to CMake in version 3.13. Here are the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/UseSWIG.html?highlight=swig_use_target_include_directories#command:swig_link_libraries).